# How to open urls with target="blank" in safari (WKWebView, webkit)

Tags: swift, xcode, webkit, wkwebview

I'm developing an app that is basically a Web View displaying a website designed to mimic an app. The majority of URLs will be internal however there will be a few which will redirect to other sites. All these links will have target="_blank".

I've spent days browsing this site and others to find a solution that will open _blank URLs in safari however everything I've tried has failed.

Any help with this would be much appreciated. I've added below the code from my View Controller

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate  {
    @IBOutlet weak var webView:WKWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        
        let myURL = URL(string:"https://example.com")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView?.load(myRequest)
        
    }}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView? {
        if let frame = navigationAction.targetFrame,
            frame.isMainFrame {
            return nil
        }
        webView.load(navigationAction.request)
        return nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace your  **createWebViewWith** with this one

```
extension ViewController: WKUIDelegate {

    //This opens maps or any other url given in new tab

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView? {

        if navigationAction.targetFrame == nil {

            webView.load(navigationAction.request)

        }

        return nil

    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for looking into this. I've replaced the code above and sadly that doesn't work. When I try and build the app I get the error: Cannot find type 'WebViewController' in scope. If I remove the first line "extension WebViewController: WKUIDelegate {" and replace it with: "extension WKWebView: WKUIDelegate {" the code will build and when using the simulator to test a link with target="_blank" when I tap on a link nothing happens.

Comment: replace WebViewController with your controller name  ViewController, or copay this function body and paste it into your function body

Comment: I updated the answer test it now  remove your createWebViewWith function and this one.